# not reading .csv with pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, graph

I am trying to read a .csv file but I have an error ParserError: **Error tokenizing data**. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 6, saw 4.
The values are inside excel boxes. not separated by commas.
An image is below:

[image]

I have tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

filename = '/users/santi/Desktop/SN16440275_300323_300323.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(filename)
```

It doesn't read the file.

I have done this:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('/users/Santi/Desktop/SN16440275_030423_030423.csv', skiprows=4, nrows=5, sep=';') # Only read rows from 5 to 9
```

And the result is:

```
                                                      Description 1\t\tDate\tTime\tStatus\t[m3] Volume\t\tVolume\t[m3] Volume
Balsa\t\t30/03/2023\t0:02\t128\t1881 09\t\t1727 32\t1881 4
Balsa\t\t30/03/2023\t6:01\t128\t1881 09\t\t1727 32\t1881 4
Balsa\t\t30/03/2023\t12:02\t128\t1881 09\t\t1727 32\t1881 4
Balsa\t\t30/03/2023\t18:02\t128\t1881 09\t\t1727 32\t1881 4
```

Its not structured correcty as in your example before. then I want to graph but its not possible

```
df.plot(x='Date', y='[m3]Volume') plt.show()
```

> KeyError: 'Date'

What can I do?

Comment: Please provide raw data not an image (first 17 lines is sufficient). [How to create a minimal reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: that 17 rows are all the file. How can I provide the raw data?

Comment: Copy/Paste into a code block in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I made a CSV file with some missing column names to simulate your sheet
[image]

Then I used `sep=;` parameter, since the CSV values are separated by columns not a comma
[image]